# Using multiple databases with peewee

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I'm writing a "multi tenant" application. It's going to be hosted on different subdomains, and based on which subdomain it's hosted, it should use a different database.

Is it possible to define, in execution time, which database peewee should be using? If I were using django, I'd just write a router that takes care of it, but I haven't found anything similar on peewee.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

PS: A hack like this [How to query several similar databases using Peewee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003916/how-to-query-several-similar-databases-using-peewee), where you need to know beforehand which class to invoke wouldn't work fine in my scenario

Comment: Can you do this in flask instead of peewee? For example, using [application factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) with [application dispatchers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/#dispatch-by-subdomain)

Comment: @Ngenator that could certainly work :) please put it as an answer so that I can at least upvote it... I like it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling this in peewee, you could handle the db selection in flask using [application factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/) with [application dispatchers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appdispatch/)

Comment: The links not exists, please fix this

Answer (score 4):

Peewee provides also the possibility to use DB Proxy, where you can switch the DB easily.
[Peewee Documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/2.10.2/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database)

```
database_proxy = Proxy()  # Create a proxy for our db.

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database_proxy  # Use proxy for our DB.

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()

# Based on configuration, use a different database.
if app.config['DEBUG']:
    database = SqliteDatabase('local.db')
elif app.config['TESTING']:
    database = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
else:
    database = PostgresqlDatabase('mega_production_db')

# Configure our proxy to use the db we specified in config.
database_proxy.initialize(database)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a look at the [ReadSlave module](http://pydoc.net/peewee/2.10.1/playhouse.read_slave/) for an example of changing databases at run-time.

Code:

```
class ReadSlaveModel(Model):
    @classmethod
    def _get_read_database(cls):
        if not getattr(cls._meta, 'read_slaves', None):
            return cls._meta.database
        current_idx = getattr(cls, '_read_slave_idx', -1)
        cls._read_slave_idx = (current_idx + 1) % len(cls._meta.read_slaves)
        return cls._meta.read_slaves[cls._read_slave_idx]

    @classmethod
    def select(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        query = super(ReadSlaveModel, cls).select(*args, **kwargs)
        query.database = cls._get_read_database()
        return query

    @classmethod
    def raw(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        query = super(ReadSlaveModel, cls).raw(*args, **kwargs)
        if query._sql.lower().startswith('select'):
            query.database = cls._get_read_database()
        return query
```

Comment: Thanks for that @coleifer! Questions: would this affect only selects? also... is there a way to define the database that all my models use in a separate place instead of the model? Ideally, it would be a config I apply (using something like dependency injection) and that would make all my models use that database. In django's ORM, that would be done at a router level.

Comment: Yeah, it was just meant as an example of how I'd done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is using a factory for the models.

```
def models_factory(database):
    class Model1(Model):
        class Meta:
            database = database
        ...

    ...

    return(locals().copy())
```

somewhere else:

```
models = models_factory(database)
models['Model1'].create_table()
```

The function creates all the models using the database passed as argument. Then returns `locals()` dict which contains all the models defined.

If you use `ForeignKeyField` then it is important that the referenced model is defined in the same function or that it is defined in the calling scope.

Alternatively you can use `DeferredForeignKey` if you want to define the models in different functions (factories):

```
def model1(database):

    class Model1(Model):
        ...

    return Model1


def model2(database)

   class Model2(Model):
       model1_id = DeferredForeignKey('Model1', field='id', ...)
       ...
   
   return Model2
```

somewhere else:

```
Model1 = model1(database)
Model2 = model2(database)
```

Also if you are using multiple databases with the same database structure you can create a `Database` class inherited from peewee database and define the factory/es as methods.

Then you could instantiate the database just as `Database(filename)` and you have all the models in there:

```
class Database(SqliteDatabase):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__(filename, pragmas={'foreign_keys': 1})
        self.models = self.create_models()
        ...

    def create_models(self)

        class Model1(Model):
            class Meta:
                database = self
            ...

        ...

        return locals().copy()
```

somewhere else:

```
db = Database("mydatabase.db")
db.models['Model1'].create_table()
```